# Mysql foreign keys / table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Table users

```
id | pseudo | firstname | email | password | ...
```

Table event

```
id | organizer | language | event_name | event_desc | event_place | ...
```

Users subscribe to multiple events.
An event can contain multiple users.

A column registered_users in table event is not the solution.

Do I alter one of tables to have a foreign Key?

Do I need one foreign key to associate to each user a list of events, and then another to associate each event to a list of users?

Comment: What is your 1 clear specific researched non-duplicate question?

Answer (score 0):

You have a many-to-many relationship and need a third table, EventUsers with columns for Event.Id and User.Id.

Answer (score 0):

Here It is up-to your need but it seems that you have to alter *Event* table and add a  Foreign Key of user_id, that can be multiple in event table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table for relation between User and Event. This table can have 3 columns, a primary key, id (foreign key from users table), id(foreign key from event table)